# No menu option to "switch user" in Cinnamon desktop

Tags: menu, cinnamon

The menu has options to lock the screen, log out and shutdown, but there isn't an option that allows me to switch to a different user. Is there another way to do that or, even better, is there a way to add that option to the global menu? I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One suggestion is to create either a *favourite* shortcut in the main menu or a *panel* shortcut.

To do this, use `alacarte` to create a shortcut to the command `gdmflexiserver`

[image]

Logout and login

Then search for your shortcut:

[image]

Right-click the menu item and choose one of the options as shown.

Answer (score 1):

on linux mint 13 cinnamon there's a "New Login" program
go to Menu --> search "new login" --> enter
it should open the mdm login window