# How do I make the Suspend Option Appear in 14.04 with Cinnamon 2.2

Tags: 14.04, suspend, cinnamon

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 13.10 with Cinnamon 2 to Ubuntu 14.04 with Cinnamon 2.2 I no longer have the option to Suspend from the shutdown menu. Closing the lid will not suspend the system either (I have this setup to suspend when on battery). I have Mate on the same system and if I login to a Mate session suspend is available and closing the lid suspends.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be create a .desktop that can do the suspend action using a command.

Please see the necessary information to create a .desktop here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/102903/352251

Then read about the potential commands to produce a supend or hibernate here:
[How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)

As an alternative you can install this applet:
http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/175